# Extract text from last line in log file using vbscript

Tags: regex, for-loop, vbscript

I have a log file formatted as such:

AssetTag USERNAME Date Time Local

---

abc123456 Sam 10/15/2015 8:22:14am Local

abc87363 Joe 10/15/2015 8:55:59am Local

---

I need to extract the USERNAME from the last line of the log file using a batch file. IE: Extract 'Joe' from the last line.

I am thinking some sort regex to find the first space and select the text between the first space and the next space...that should be 'Joe'...

I am using this to extract the last line:

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\logs\UserAudit.log", ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If Len(strNextLine) > 0 Then
        strLine = strNextLine
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close

Wscript.Echo strLine
```

EDIT: it is actually 2 tabs that separate the assettag and the username and 1 tab that separate the username and the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with a little more google...

What the below script does..

1) Prompt for asset tag
2) reads last line from log file, extracts username
3)looks up username in AD to find the Staff Name

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strAsset= INPUTBOX("Please enter the Asset Tag:")
strLog = "\\" & strAsset & "\C$\Logs\UserAudit.log"

'Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\logs\UserAudit.log", ForReading)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strLog, ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If Len(strNextLine) > 0 Then
        strLine = strNextLine
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close
intStart = InStr(strLine, "     ")
If intStart <> 0 Then
        intStart = intStart + 2
        strText = Mid(strLine, intStart, 250)
        For i = 1 to Len(strText)
            If Mid(strText, i, 1) = "   " Then
                Exit For
            Else
                strData = strData & Mid(strText, i, 1)
            End If
        Next
    End If

'Username from Log file
Wscript.Echo strData

'Lookup Account for Staff Name

SET objSystemInfo = CREATEOBJECT("ADSystemInfo") 
strDomain = objSystemInfo.DomainShortName
strUser = strData

wscript.echo GetUserDN(strUser,strDomain)
strAD = GetUserDN(strUser,strDomain)

intStart = InStr(strAD, "CN=")
If intStart <> 0 Then
        intStart = intStart + 3
        strText = Mid(strAD, intStart, 250)
        For i = 1 to Len(strText)
            If Mid(strText, i, 3) = ",OU" Then
                Exit For
            Else
                strName = strName & Mid(strText, i, 1)
            End If
        Next
    End If
wScript.echo strName

FUNCTION GetUserDN(BYVAL strUserName,BYVAL strDomain)
    SET objTrans = CREATEOBJECT("NameTranslate")
    objTrans.Init 1, strDomain
    objTrans.SET 3, strDomain & "\" & strUserName 
    strUserDN = objTrans.GET(1) 
    GetUserDN = strUserDN
END FUNCTION

'Cleanup
intStart=""
strUser=""
strDomain=""
strName=""
strAD=""
strText=""
strLine=""
strNextLine=""
```